# Change text direction RTL in LibreOffice on mac

Tags: macos, mac, libreoffice, right-to-left

I have marked the checkbox for CTL on language options and I can choose the Right-To-Left button,
But on OSX EL Capitan when I type in Hebrew the text gets choppy and the cursor jump the the beginning of the word after I press space.

I can't use this great tool.
By the way I use **Libreoffice 5.0.4**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed an Older version of **LibreOffice 4.X** and Hebrew text (RTL) works flawlessly.

The fresh install 5.X doesn't yet work very well with Hebrew (RTL).

This was tested only on **MAC OSX EL Capitan**

Comment: I have tested the latest version of libreoffice 5.1.3 and this issue still exists

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the cursor is actually in the correct place but is just getting displayed in the wrong place.  I have experienced this with right-to-left scripts on some systems.  To test this:

1. In a new document, type one word, press space, then type another word.
2. Save as PDF.

Are the words rendered correctly in the PDF file?

You may find that the [stable version](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-still/) has more reliable rendering than the "fresh" 5.x series.  I have had trouble with several scripts when using 5.x, probably because it has not been tested well enough yet.

Also try using a different font.  Be sure to use a Unicode font such as [Ezra SIL](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ezrasil_home) so that the word processor can interpret the symbols correctly.

Apparently some people have had success with Hebrew and LibreOffice on OS X.  Search for "LibreOffice" on https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-a-document-right-to-left-e-g-in-Hebrew-on-a-Mac.

Comment: I did what you have suggested and the PDF looks good, I have also installed an older version 4.X and RTL works well, So I think I will stick to the older version for now ! Thanks for the quick response !